# Meteor - Select Parent ID of element clicked

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Using Meteor, I am trying to loop through and display a list of notes from a database with an option to delete each note.

Here is the HTML (using Handlebars.js)

```
<template name="Notes">
    {{#each NoteArr}}
        <div class="Note">
            <h2>{{Title}}</h2>
            <p>{{Body}}</p>
            <span class="deleteNote">Delete</span>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And here is the client Javascript

```
Template.Notes.events = {
    "click .deleteNote" : function(){
        noteID = $('.deleteNote').parent().attr("id");
        Notes.remove({ID:noteID});
    }
};
```

This grabs the first instance of .deleteNote, so unless I'm trying to delete the first one, that won't help. How can I grab the parent of the particular instance of .deleteNote that was clicked, not just the first one it finds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the first element is deleted is.. in your `.click` event, you are accesssing the div directly as `$('.deleteNote').parent()` which grabs the first node in the html which has a class `.deleteNode`.

**Now to remove the specific `notes`, from the collection:**  Every document in the collection has a unique `_id` attribute which is generated automatically. assign that unique `_id` of the document to the span element as `<span id= "{{_id}}" class="deleteNote">Delete</span>`.

So the cilck event will look like:

```
 Template.Notes.events = {
    "click .deleteNote" : function(e){
        var noteID = e.currentTarget.id;
        Notes.remove({_id:noteID});
        }
   };
```

And the template will look like:

```
<template name="Notes">
    {{#each NoteArr}}
        <div class="Note">
            <h2>{{Title}}</h2>
            <p>{{Body}}</p>
            <span id= "{{_id}}" class="deleteNote">Delete</span>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Untested code, but hope this will help solving your issue.

Answer (score 4):

The _id of a note is stored in 'this' as well. In addition, the remove function accepts '_id' as a string. So this should work as well:

```
Template.Notes.events = {
  'click .deleteNote': function(){ return Notes.remove(this._id)}
}
```

A few benefits here. Less querying the DOM for information. Less jQuery. Fewer lines of code to think about. Cleaner templates.

Comment: Did not know that _id was propgated in 'this'. Very nice, very clean.